# SQL Server datetime conversion Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to insert a `datetime` value into `datetime` column in SQL Server 2005

I am passing `DateTime` variable from the .aspx page

Which needs to be inserted in the column.

Example:

```
Table(date datetime)

@sql = 'insert into Table (date) values('+@datetime+')'
exec(@sql)
```

getting conversion failed message.

Any idea how to do this.

Very Urgent.

Thanks.

Comment: Inserting dates as string is almost always dependent on your language/regional settings. What does your string `@datetime` look like?? If ever possible, use the ISO-8601 format: `YYYYMMDD` which always works, regardless of your date format settings.

Comment: Can you show your asp.net that calls the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need string delimiters - in T-SQL this is doubled-up single quotes.

```
SET @sql = 'insert into Table (date) values('''+@datetime+''')'
exec(@sql)
```

However it still might fail, depending on the format of the string. Any reason you're building a SQL string, prone to SQL injection, instead of just saying:

```
INSERT Table(date) SELECT @datetime;
```

?

Comment: Thnaks. I made the string as below at sql server                       declare @datetime datetime
set @datetime='07/01/2011'
declare @sql varchar(500)
set @sql='insert into tbl_Quality_VS_Audits(auditdate)
values('''+convert(varchar,@datetime,101)+''')'

Comment: Still don't understand. Why do you need to create a @sql string? Why don't you just run `INSERT tbl_Quality_VS_Audits(auditdate) SELECT @datetime;` ?

Comment: That is not the only string I need to insert I have few more parameters I have just given a simple scenario

Answer (score 1):

Add escaped single quotes around the datetime value.  Normally they are passed as strings.

See if this works:

```
@sql = 'insert into Table (date) values('''+@datetime+''')'
exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your query/stored procedure are expecting to receive the parameter as a `datetime` variable (not `varchar(20)`, or anything else like that), and make sure your ASP.Net code is passing the value as a `datetime` value also.

Basically, for best datetime handling, convert them from strings into datetimes as early as possible when accepting them as input (e.g. convert them in an appropriate event in your code behind in ASP.NET), keep them as datetimes whenever passing them to/from the database, and fromat them back as strings as late as possible when outputting them (e.g. in view code for asp.net mvc, or when assigning to the Text property of an ASP.Net control)

Answer (score 0):

Try making this small change to your sql statement

```
@sql = "insert into Table (date) values ('"+ @datetime + "')"
```

Comment: If @sql is being defined on the T-SQL side, the double-quotes won't work (Msg 207).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other suggestions with delimiters and parenthesis mismatches, Date is a reserved keyword, use [Date] instead.

Comment: So is Table. :-) I assume these are simply placeholder names that don't really represent the underlying schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @datetime datetime
Set @datetime=GetDate()

Declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
Declare @param nvarchar(1000)
Set @param='@datetime datetime'

SET @sql = 'insert into Table (date) values(@datetime)'

exec sp_executesql @sql,@param,@datetime
```

you have to learn the sql injection for dynamic queries.